# My WordPress site is down, how can I restart it?

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform

I cannot reach my WordPress blog. I had an email from a GCP support person but I lost it. I recall it was talking about my SSHing into the server. Not sure what else as I lost that email. What can I do to get my blog back?

Kindly,
Robert

Comment: [ask] and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I concur with what support has told you on your case, please [try another VM with more memory](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance) or [modify the one you have](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/changing-machine-type-of-stopped-instance).

Comment: I restarted the instance and it is now working. I did not change th machine type , as i had huge confusion over how to do so. Now I see the instructions for editing the instance [2]. I changed to 'n1-standard-2'. All is well!

Answer (score 2):

Best: Contact GCP support

We have no way of knowing what kind of plan you have, what it includes, what restrictions it has, or any valuable info.

Comment: I sent feedback, the only way I could figure how to contact GCP Support.

In the meantime, how can I SSH into my server instance? Isn't SSH a way to restart my WordPress instance?

Kindly, 
Robert

Comment: Unless you know your server's IP, and have SSH credentials or ssh_key setup, you cannot login via SSH. If you are asking here, I would assume you do not have this info or the knowledge. I would suggest to try and dig up that email they sent you so you can login to GC and work from there..